# Error in displaying HTML Element in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have the following lines of code:

```
if @browser.text_field(:id => "street").exists?
      puts "street exist"
      puts @browser.text_field(:id => "street").html
    else
      puts "street does not exist"
    end
```

But after running this one, I've got an error:

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

street exist
E

Finished tests in 90.183158s, 0.0111 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_login(TC_Login):
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: invalid 'in' operand a
    [remote server] http://sam.org/user/ line 68 > Function:18:in `G'
    [remote server] http://sam.org/user/ line 68 > Function:18:in `anonymous/</<'
    [remote server] http://sam.org/user/ line 68 > Function:15:in `anonymous/<'
    [remote server] http://sam.org/user/ line 68 > Function:15:in `anonymous'
    [remote server] http://sam.org/user/:68:in `handleEvaluateEvent'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:640:in `raw_execute'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:618:in `execute'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:339:in `executeScript'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:193:in `execute_script'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/atoms.rb:20:in `execute_atom'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:290:in `outer_html'
    excel.rb:279:in `test_login'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

The element already exists. And when I try `puts @browser.html`, it displays the whole page source. My goal is to display only a specific HTML Element. And I tried the lines of code above. And I can't understand what the error says.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `puts` the text in the `text_field`?  It's hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: I am asking for the specific page source of the element

Comment: Are you using FF35?  Sounds like it.  If so, it's been having [issues](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390), so you might want to downgrade to FF34.  `@browser.text_field(:id => "foo").html` should return the HTML for the specific element, and `@browser.text_field(:id => "foo").value` should return the text within the text field. YMMV.

Comment: execute_script is currently broken for Firefox 35, the fix will be ready whenever WebDriver 2.45 is released.

Actually, you want 
    @browser.text_field(:id => "foo").text to return the text in the text field. If there is a value attribute in the tag, value would return that.

Comment: FF35? Is that firefox version 35? Yes. I am using that one. But how can I downgrade it to FF34?

Comment: Try this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, as this would go specific to the element.

```
@browser.find_element(:id, "street")
```

Comment: find_element method is undefine for Watir. And the alternative method for that is @browser.element(:id, "street"). But the error I have got is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
puts @browser.text_field(:id => "street").value if @browser.text_field(:id => "street").exists?
```